# How to Connect to SQL database using Sharepoint 2010/Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-designer, database, external-content-type, office-365, secure-store

How do you get into the Central administration page and create a secure store application ID?

I am trying to connect to an external database and cannot do so with my current credentials.  I have a username and password for the external database but would like to access it through sharepoint.

I've tried going into Sharepoint Designer -> External Content Types -> Add connection -> SQL -> And I have filled in my credentials and still cannot connect.

We use office 365.

Thanks,
Catherine

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong, you cannot connect to the SQL DB from oficce 365, but you can try to solve this issue as described in this [solution](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/SharePoint-Online-and-External-Data-using-JSONP.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Very good detailed article on this :

http://fabiangwilliams.wordpress.com/2010/04/16/how-to-create-configure-consume-sharepoint-2010-secure-store-in-business-connectivity-services/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2010/01/27/setting-up-bcs-with-secure-store-application-impersonation.aspx

http://wyldesharepoint.blogspot.com/2010/06/setting-up-external-content-type-for.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3rd party to secure connect your SQL to O365. See here how it works for ODBC, OLEDB, Microsoft .NET based providers, Files (Excel, XML, CSV), RSS / XML feeds, SQL databases like MS SQL, SQL Azure, Oracle, MySQL, IBM DB2, IBM AS/400, IBM Informix, Notes, SharePoint (lists and libraries), local file system, Exchange, Active Directory, Dynamics NAV/CRM, Navision, SAP and many more. More complex data sources, web services, custom COM or .NET objects, can be connected using 3rd party add-ons. Cloud-to-cloud connections e.g. to salesforce.com,  Twitter, Facebook, Google etc.

[image: Cloud Connector Architecture]

You can download here:
http://www.layer2.de/en/products/Pages/Cloud-Connector-for-SharePoint-2010-Office365.aspx

Thanks, Frank